# Do Newey-West standard errors correct for Stambaugh bias?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, prediction

I was wondering if Newey-West standard errors correct the [Stambaugh bias](http://finance.wharton.upenn.edu/~stambaug/bias_reg.pdf) when you have lagged stochastic regressors? The bias is also explained [here](http://schwert.ssb.rochester.edu/f533/jfe99_rs.pdf).

I know that [Hodrick (1992)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/5/3/357/1576229) would correct for the Stambaugh bias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just learning about Stambaugh bias now.  Take my advice with a grain of salt.

### Stambaugh Bias

From what I gathered the Stambaugh bias occurs when you are regressing specific types of financial data.  Specifically, the target variable has a casual impact on the lagged predictors.  This violates one of the fundamental assumptions of OLS, i.e. $E(u|x) = 0$ (where $u$ is the residual and $x$ the regressors).  This will always lead to a biased estimator.

To better understand the bias, Stambaugh states $x_t = \alpha + \rho x_{t-1} + v_t$.  According to the paper, the bias can't be corrected, as it relies on the true coefficients and var-covar matrix of above equation (which are unknown).  (Side note: In practice, I don't see why you can't correct for the bias with estimates. Especially when $x_t$ does not follow a stochastic trend).

### Newey-West

Serial correlation is a very different problem.  It occurs when a completely different OLS assumption is violated (i.e. $E(uu') =\sigma I$).  Serial correlation actually does not result in a biased estimator (though it does decrease it's efficiency).  NW estimator address serial correlation by modeling errors with an AR process.  This might be where you're getting confused.

Alternatively, if you're saying you want to correct the SB by obtaining estimates of the var-covar matrix.  Then it might be a good idea. As mentioned above, estimates of the var-covar matrix are needed to correct the bias.  However, as mentioned Stambaugh 1999, the limiting distribution of the estimator is also not the typical normal.  So even if you correct the bias, you can't do traditional t-tests.

This might help https://www.bauer.uh.edu/rsusmel/phd/lecture%205.pdf